# How to define typescript types when passing react component as property to a react component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to implement a compound design pattern. For this, I have to pass a react component as a property to another react component.

Here is the code:

```
function FlyOut(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}

function Toggle() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Icon />
    </div>
  );
}

FlyOut.Toggle = Toggle;
```

Since I am using typescript I will have to specify types to these components.

Without this statement: `FlyOut.Toggle = Toggle;`. I specified the typescript types as follows:

```
type FlyoutProp={
    children?: ReactNode | undefined;
}


function FlyOut=React.FC<FlyoutProp>(props)=> {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}

function Toggle:React.FC<void> =()=> {
  return (
    <div>
      <Icon />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now that I add this statement  `FlyOut.Toggle = Toggle;`

I tried this:

```
type FlyoutProps = {
    children?: ReactNode | undefined;
};

type ExtendedReactFC = React.FC<FlyoutProps> & {
    Toggle?: ReactNode | undefined;
};

function FlyOut=ExtendedReactFC<FlyoutProp>(props)=> {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}

function Toggle:React.FC<void> =()=> {
  return (
    <div>
      <Icon />
    </div>
  );
}

FlyOut.Toggle = Toggle;
```

But this did not work. Please can anyone guide me/

Comment: Why do you do this `FlyOut.Toggle = Toggle`?

Comment: For implementing a compound pattern

Comment: `type ExtendedReactFC = React.FC<FlyoutProps> & {
    Toggle: React.FC<void>;
};`

Comment: Thanks for help but it  didn't worked

Comment: Can you try to change `ExtendedReactFC<FlyoutProp>` to `ExtendedReactFC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `ExtendedReactFC<FlyoutProp>` to `ExtendedReactFC` because `ExtendedReactFC` doesn't accept generic type

```
type FlyoutProps = {
    children?: ReactNode | undefined;
};

type ExtendedReactFC = React.FC<FlyoutProps> & {
    Toggle?: ReactNode | undefined;
};

function FlyOut=ExtendedReactFC(props)=> {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you want to make it accept generic type props you can change it to

```
type FlyoutProps = {
    children?: ReactNode | undefined;
};

type ExtendedReactFC<T extends Record<string,any>> = React.FC<T> & {
    Toggle?: ReactNode | undefined;
};

function FlyOut=ExtendedReactFC<FlyoutProps>(props)=> {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}
```